# As a Teams admin, can I create Slack notifications on behalf of a team member?

Tags: support, status-declined, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'm looking to set up Slack notifications on behalf of some Team members (without having to sign in as them). In the admin settings, I'm able to see which notifications have already been set up, but is there a way to create new ones that are only going to be triggered based on @ mentions of a particular Team member?

Comment: Before we gut-react to this:  this is an [officially supported thing](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000189501-slack-integration-overview) that someone who supports Teams should be answering.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Sorry! I've updated the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not currently support the creation of Slack notifications on behalf of another user. I've have added this request to our feature request tracker for consideration in a future update.